# Gnome 3 and discrete only nvidia

Tags: gnome, drivers, nvidia

Long ago I've installed Gnome 3 over Ubuntu 12.10

Currently I'm working on a scientific project, that requires lot of graphical work. I'd like notebook to run nvidia GPU only. So I disabled nvidia optimus in BIOS and switched to use discrete videocard.

But now gnome 3 is not loading. It stucks at blue scree. What can I do ?

I also was unable to install nvidia drivers. I'm working on thinkpad W520 with Quadro K2000m. If there's a manual on how to install nvidia drivers - it would be cool.

Answer (score 0):

the following post worked for me
http://falkvinge.net/2013/02/15/how-to-install-nvidia-drivers-in-ubuntu-12-10-quantal/

kr raphael